# Remove element by key from all the objects inside an object

Tags: javascript

I have this object :

```
const test = {
    "/test2": {
        "path": "/test",
        "items": [{
            "path": "/test",
            "method": "GET",
        }, {
            "path": "/test",
            "method": "PUT",
        }]
    },
    "/test": {
        "path": "/test2",
        "items": [{
            "path": "/test2",
            "method": "GET",
        }]
    }
}
```

And i would like to delete the nested element `path` which is inside each of the objects so that i can have in the end something like this :

```
const test = {
    "/test": {
        "path": "/test",
        "items": [{
            "method": "GET",
        }, {
            "method": "PUT",
        }]
    },
    "/test2": {
        "path": "/test2",
        "items": [{
            "method": "GET",
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Array.prototype.filter?

Comment: I have an object of objects here :/

Comment: You have an array of objects. Your output shows that you want to remove `path` from all elements inside `items`.

Comment: Then you could use `Object.keys(test).filter(key => { /* filter your test[key].path */ })`

Comment: oh yes it worked, sorry it go out of my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
const data = {
  "/test2": {
    "path": "/test",
    "items": [{
      "path": "/test",
      "method": "GET",
    }, {
      "path": "/test",
      "method": "PUT",
    }]
  },
  "/test": {
    "path": "/test2",
    "items": [{
      "path": "/test2",
      "method": "GET",
    }]
  }
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
  data[k].items.forEach(item => {
    delete item['path']
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufb72pgL/)

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into array. Use `reduce` to loop thru the array. Use `map` to loop thru `items` and only return the `method`

```js
const test = {"/test2":{"path":"/test","items":[{"path":"/test","method":"GET"},{"path":"/test","method":"PUT"}]},"/test":{"path":"/test2","items":[{"path":"/test2","method":"GET"}]}};

const result = Object.entries(test).reduce((c, [k, {path,items}]) => {
  c[k] = {path};
  c[k].items = items.map(({method}) => ({method}));
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop through the keys of `test`. And then use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and `delete` to remove the `path` from each object in `items`:

```js
const test = { "/test": { path: "/test", items: [{ path: "/test", method: "GET" }, { path: "/test", method: "PUT" }] }, "/test2": { path: "/test2", items: [{ path: "/test2", method: "GET", }] } };

for (let key in test) {
  for (let item of test[key].items) {
    delete item.path
  }
}

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an recursive and iterative approach by deleting the unwanted property and iterate all nested values of the object.

```js
function delKey(key) {
    return function d(object) {
        if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
        delete object[key];
        Object.values(object).forEach(d);
    };
}

const test = { "/test": { path: "/test", items: [{ path: "/test", method: "GET" }, { path: "/test", method: "PUT" }] }, "/test2": { path: "/test2", items: [{ path: "/test2", method: "GET", }] } };

delKey('path')(test);
console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```